# Prove that the Michael line is not metrizable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

**Exercise** Show that the Michael Line is not metrizable.

> The Michael line is given by $\{U \cup A: U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ usual topology and $A \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\}$

> Note that in a metric space, closed sets are $G_\delta$ sets, i.e. the countable intersection of open sets.

---

*Proof*

To see that the Michael line $\mathbb{M}$ is not metrizable, to derive a contradiction, suppose that $\mathbb{M}$ is metrizable. We may treat $\mathbb{M}$ as a metric space. Let $E$ be closed in $\mathbb{M}$. Since $E$ is closed, then $E$ is the countable intersection of $\mathbb{M}$-open sets, i.e.

$$E = \displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (U_i \cup A_i)$$

It follows then that the complelement $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ is given by

$$\mathbb{R} \setminus E = \mathbb{R} \setminus \displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (U_i \cup A_i)$$

Since $E$ is $G_\delta$, then $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ is $F_\sigma$, a countable union of closed sets.

$$\mathbb{R} \setminus \displaystyle\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (U_i \cup A_i) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R} \setminus (U_i \cup A_i)$$

I seem to have run into a wall at this point. Where can I derive a contradiction? Any advice would be of great value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Michael line, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a closed set but not a $G_\delta$ set.

**Proof:**

$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} $ is an open set, so $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed.

***Suppose*** you have a pair of sequences $U_n$ and $B_n$,

such that $U_n$ is an open set in the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$

and $B_n\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$.

***Suppose furthermore*** that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \bigcap_{n}(U_n\cup B_n)$.

Now, $\mathbb{Q}\subset \bigcap_{n}U_n$,

since each $B_n$ does not contain any rational number.

This means $\mathbb{Q}\subset U_n$ for all $n$,

which in turn means $U_n=\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

The conclusion is $\bigcap_{n}(U_n\cup B_n)=\mathbb{R}$,

so that $\bigcap_{n}(U_n\cup B_n)$ is not equal to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How does this show that $\mathbb{M}$ is not metrizable?

Comment: If you can find a closed set that is not a $G_\delta$ set, then the topology is not metrizable

Comment: I do not see how your proof illustrates that $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{M}$, however

Comment: just directly apply the definition of which subsets of the Michael line are open

Comment: $\emptyset$ is open in the usual Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Therefore, $\emptyset\cup(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is open in the Michael line